# How do I adjust margin-top attribute depending on length of php title?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm building a custom template in Wordpress.

I need the title of the page to auto adjust itself if it is larger than 45 characters.

The title is being pulled from the Wordpress database via PHP.

I am trying to build javascript to do this:

If the length of the title (via php) is < 45 characters: change the css attribute "margin-top"  to 111px.

Else change the css attribute "margin-top" to 150px.

Here is what I have so far:

My HTML:

```
<div class="title-of-page" id="title" style="margin-top:53px">
    <?php echo get_the_title($post->post_parent); ?>
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
<script>
if ( <? php strlen(get_the_title($post - > post_parent)) ?> < 45) {
    document.getElementById("title").style.marginTop = "111px";
} else {
    document.getElementById("title").style.marginTop = "150px";
} 
</script>
```

Ask questions if I'm not being clear enough.

Comment: If you calculate the length of the title by PHP, why are you manipulating the `margin` property by JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry Hashem, I don't understand.  I feel like this should work but it doesn't.

Comment: Since you want to manipulate the margin using javascript, it is preferrable to get it's computed value using javascript, not php

Comment: But the only way I can dynamically get the title is by PHP since it sits in my wordpress database.  Is there something I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why javascript?

```
<?php
$title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
if (strlen($title)<45) { $mtop ='111px'; } else { $mtop='150px'; }
echo '<div class="title-of-page" id="title" style="margin-top:'.$mtop.';">'.$title.'</div>';
?>
```

Comment: holy crap... that is amazing.

Comment: Good solution. But in general Chaddly, changing style on the fly is a bad practice which could lead to a weak performance because it makes the browser redraw elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in PHP only as @Thomas Martin suggested.

However if you are too keen to do it at the Javascript Side.You can do it by .

```
<script>
   var title =  document.getElementById('title').textContent;
   if(title.length < 45){
       document.getElementById("title").style.marginTop = "111px";
   }else{
       document.getElementById("title").style.marginTop = "150px";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: This is nice and the answer I was previously looking for.  I am going to use PHP for simplicity reasons.